# AWS Amplify: useAuthenticator hook do not cause a re-render on user.attributes field change

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, react-context

In my React project i use Amplify `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.17.1"`, `"aws-amplify": "^4.3.22"`, and i faced with unexpected behaviour.

I doing `import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';` into my component to get user data (issue exists with both approaches):

```
const { user } = useAuthenticator();
const { user } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
```

I also do `import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';` and make a function to update user attribute - `given_name`.

```
const setAttr = async () => {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, { given_name: 'Eddie' });
    const res = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.attributes));
  };
```

After running this function i see correct value in `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.attributes));` inside function.
But `const { user } = useAuthenticator();` still see values from initial render (old name). I checked it by declaring `setInterval(() => console.log(user.attributes), 1000);` and comparing values.
So, value in context do not change => component do not re-render => i see old `given_name` until i reload page.

**My solution for now**: i'm duplicating `given_name` in store, after successful request change it to a new value that cause a rerender.

**Unacceptable solution**: location.reload().

**Solution i'm looking for**: after changing `given_name` field, `useAuthenticator` track this change and cause a rerender, so i do not need duplicating this logic in store.

**UPD**: Noticed that it works as expected in **deployed version**. But it do not work on localhost, so makes development process
inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I found the expected behavior on the deployed version, I tried to figure out what was wrong on localhost. Removing `<StrictMode>` from `index.tsx` in the root of a project solved the problem on localhost as well. I'm going to create an issue for them on github about it.

Comment: Can you please link the issue?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/2495